# Java Character change of a String

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

i have java String variables format with(include spaces)  `String id = "CA T 4443"` i need to get my String value as `id=CA4443` need to remove T and spaces. can any java expert help me to concatenate these characters.

```
my value array
CA T 4443
CB T 4562
CG T 6365
DA T 5552
CX T 9875
CS T 5454
RA T 2377
```

second challenge

```
CAF T 444352
CBAD T 4562
CG T 636535
DA T 555255
CX T 98755665
CS T 545455
RA T 237766
```

i need to get as (only 1st two latter and last 4 digits)

```
CA4352
CB4562
CG6535
DA5255
CX5665
CS5455
RA7766
```

Comment: Hint : google `java, replace, string`

Comment: id.replace(char oldChar, char newChar)

Answer (score 2):

If it is always two lettes, a space, a T, and a number then you could do :

```
String id = "CA T 4443"
String result = id.substring(0, 2) + id.substring(5, id.length);
```

Or you could just do :

```
String result = id.replace(" T ", "");
```

Comment: excellent..but i need to catch only 1st two latter and last 4 digits (see the update)

Comment: and this is gonna catch the first two letters and last 4 digits, have you tried it ? Actually replace id.length by 9 if you want it to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
public static String getFormatedValue(String data) {
    String[] split = data.split(" ", 3);
    return split[0] + split[2];
}
```

This will take the first and last section, and skip the middle `T` section.

Answer (score 0):

You have several things going on - it's hard to tell what's the best approach without seeing the raw data.

- easiest / most fragile: if you know for a fact that every line is exactly the same length, "CA T 4443" you can just manually grab the characters at that position with substring or directly from the char array. This will break if one line is larger, probably safer to trim() the string before calling substring
- or you can call split:
  String id = "CA T 4443";
  String[] split = id.split(" "); -> gives ["CA","T", "4443"]

  A bit more flexible with lengths but depends on formatting. Splitting on a regex for whitespace if your data is possibly dirty
- or just grab pieces through regex matching.

Depends on how normalized your data is.

Comment: good explanation..i have second challenge also. if i have values with different(see update)length how to get only 1st 2 latter and only last 4 latter(digits) as a result.

Comment: Think about what you're asking. You have a given string and you want to get the first 2 or the last 4 characters? If you look in the string api, you can get the length of the string (length()), substrings by position (substring()), or if you prefer a character at a given position (charAt()). This should give you all you need to know to put this together.

Comment: yes.. i done with adding `String result =Str.substring(0, 2) + Str.substring(Str.length() - 4);`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: For the firtst challenge only**

If it is always that the IDs have T between the two "segments" you are trying to concatenate, then following is my solution:

```
public static String makeID(String[] myValueArray){
    String newID = "";
    for (String s: myValueArray){
        String[] previousID = s.split(" T ");
        newID = newID + previousID[0] + previousID[1] + "\n"; 
    }

    return newID;
}
```

Comment: You take an array of IDs and return a single string of all the IDs together? I don't think that's what the question was asking for.

Comment: @BrandonBuck, interestingly, the "second challenge" was not loaded when I gave the solution! Put it in the edit. My solution is for the "first challenge" only then... and the question did not mention about the means of input and output. So, I just assumed it in this way.

Comment: My response was about the original question. It's pretty clear your solution produces the wrong output. He wants a solution to apply per line to get the id he needs. Your solution takes an array of input ids and builds one string with all the new ids which will not produce the desired result. Also, when doing a lot of work with building strings you should be using StringBuilder.

Comment: @BrandonBuck Your solution takes an array of input ids and builds one string with all the new ids which will not produce the desired result---my output matches with what he has given before. If he needs to get the ID's individually then he had to explicitly mention it. Also, when doing a lot of work with building strings you should be using StringBuilder---Agreed.